# Spotify API Get Recently Played Track for Multiple Users

Tags: spotify

I'm building a web app that will display most popular song for my user base.
In Spotify API docs I call [Get Recently Played Tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-recently-played)

It works fine for the first users however when I'm looping to the second (third and so on) I get a 504 error.
I've checked Spotify forms and looked for other recommendations but unfortunately I've not seen another way without looping through each users and calling the Get Recently Played Tracks.

I also tried spacing out my calls to Spotify (every 1 min, 5min, etc.) with no luck.

Code that is throwing the error:

```
private async Task<SpotifyRecentlyPlayedModel> GetSpotifyRecentlyPlayedData(DateTime afterTime, string AccessToken, long SpotifyUserMappingId)
        {
            long afterTimeTimestamp = new DateTimeOffset(afterTime).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            //await Task.Delay(1000);
            string requestURI = $"https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?after={afterTimeTimestamp}";

            using (HttpClient client = new())
            {
                using HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Get, requestURI);
                request.Headers.Clear();
                request.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
                
                using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    SpotifyRecentlyPlayedModel result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpotifyRecentlyPlayedModel>(apiResponse);
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                     = await spotifyDataErrorLogRepository.AddAsync(new()
                    {
                        SpotifyUserMappingId = SpotifyUserMappingId,
                        ErrorCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
                        ErrorMessage = response.ReasonPhrase
                    });
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: can you share your code for reproducing your problem?

Comment: @BenchVue I've updated the post to include the code that is throwing an error.

Comment: We have the same issue - receiving 504s fairly consistently when accessing this endpoint. Has anyone found a work-around for this instability?

Comment: I received a response in the Spotify form that said to apply for an extension because the dev version is "limited", going through the process to see if that will resolve the issue